# mySQL for multi table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with 3 columns each such as :

```
Table 1: Col1, Col2, Col3
Table 2: Col1, Col2, Col3    
Table 3: Col1, Col2, Col3
```

I want to compare all Col3 columns to find all identical and not identical items  between Col3 columns for all 3 tables.

I am trying (in mySQL):

```
SELECT table1.Col2,table1.Col3,table2.Col2,table2.Col3, table3.Col2,table3.Col3 
FROM table1    
  INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.col3 = table1.col3    
  UNION    
FROM table1    
  INNER JOIN table1 ON table3.col3 = table1.col3    
  UNION    
FROM table2    
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table3.col3 = table2.col3
```

and for not identical list for Col3:

adding:

```
WHERE Table1.Col3 IS NULL and 
Table2.Col3 IS NULL and 
Table3.Col3 IS NULL
```

without much success. Any help would be much appreciated.....

Comment: Your code isn't even close to valid. `UNION` is used to combine the results of multiple `SELECT` queries, you can't write `UNION FROM`, it should be `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...`. I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Can you show some sample input data and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to find values which are common for all three tables in col3... If that's your question you can do that by INNER JOIN and here is how:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col3) AS IdenticalValuesInAll
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.col3 = t2.col3
INNER JOIN t3
ON t1.col3 = t3.col3 OR t2.col3 = t3.col3;
```

Here I create an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc546f/3) so you can see how it's work... (You'll notice that number that are common for all three tables in column col3 are 11 and 23)

If you want to select col1, col2, col3 from table1 (t1 in my example) where in col3 have value which is common for all three table than you simple do something like this

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.col3 = t2.col3
INNER JOIN t3
ON t1.col3 = t3.col3 OR t2.col3 = t3.col3;
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc546f/4) for that.

Now if you want to select rows (col1, col2, col3) from some table where in col3 there is not a common value for all tables you could do something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM t1
WHERE col3 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col3) AS commonForAllTables
                   FROM t1
                   INNER JOIN t2
                   ON t1.col3 = t2.col3
                   INNER JOIN t3
                   ON t1.col3 = t3.col3 OR t2.col3 = t3.col3);
```

Of course here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc546f/9) to see how that look like...

Now if you want to make one big table from this table which will contain all rows from this three table than you use UNION ALL

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM t2
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM t3;
```

And here is result of that query in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc546f/10)

And you can manipulate with that big table what ever you like.

Here is example where we going to select all rows from all three table (from the big one) where col3 don't contain similar value in all three table

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM (SELECT col1, col2, col3
      FROM t1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT col1, col2, col3
      FROM t2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT col1, col2, col3
      FROM t3) bigTable
WHERE col3 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col3) AS commonForAllTables
                   FROM t1
                   INNER JOIN t2
                   ON t1.col3 = t2.col3
                   INNER JOIN t3
                   ON t1.col3 = t3.col3 OR t2.col3 = t3.col3);
```

And here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc546f/11) for that query!

Of course if you want to select all values from all three tables which only have common values in col3 than in WHERE clause instead of NOT IN use just IN and it will work.

About INNER JOIN, UNION etc you can find a lot of material online so just google a little I don't think that i should explain here how it's work because I think I can't explain it better then those guys who already wrote whole article about that.

Comment: Thank you @Aleksandar Miladinovic. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I have a question though. In the big table query:WHERE col3 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col3) AS commonForAllTables.......                                 Why there two numbers of 14?  col3 should not contain similar value in all three table? Also, for similar col3 values in all 3 tables   (WHERE col3  IN (SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col3) AS ....),  I do not see two numbers of 14?

Comment: @Thomas For example if we have 5 rows in t1 with value 14 in col3 all that rows will be included in result with this query because there is no rows in table t3 with value 14 in col3. In this case we have two rows with value 14 in col3 one in t1 and one in t2 but in table t3 we don't have row like that so rows are included in result. We exclude rows where in t1, t2 and t3 we have similar value in col3. If we add one more row in t3 where value in col3 would be 14 then all that rows will be excluded from result. Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: I thought the query does take into account similarity between any two columns… I need and I am trying to modify big table query code to exclude 14 as similar numbers from t1.col3 and t2.col3 (as well in case of t1.col3 and t3.col3 and t2.col3 and t3.col3). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Thomas oh well i didn't understand that is requirement.. Take a look at this query [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc546f/13), it will do the job but it's a little ugly, I don't have much time those day to try to find more elegant way of solving this problem but if I find some free time I will deal with it. GL! P.S. If you find my answer useful please vote it up

Comment: @Aleksandar_Miladovic, I thank you for your answer. It seems that my vote is not counted yet due to my low reputation score. I hope I will do it later. Thanks, again.